# CakePHP Multiple record tagging

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm fairly new to CakePHP, but think I understand the basics pretty well.  I'm developing a livestock management system for a client and have run into a roadblock that I can't figure out how to approach.  They would like a bulk sale process to work like this:

- All Available animals displayed
- Mark 1-n animals for sale
- Add some additional information (IE: Buyer, total weight of the lot, etc)
- Create sales record and update the sold animal's records

What I'm struggling with is how to complete the second step in this process with Cake.  My thought was to show them with a checkbox using the forms helper, but that doesn't seem to be working like I want it to.  I'm creating a list of the available animals and passing it to the view for display in a table, adding the checkboxes for each row.
Here is a snippet of what I currently have in the view:

```
<div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="50%">
     <?php 
        echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(
            array(
            'Row Number',
            'Ear Tag',
            'Name',
            array('Actions' => array('width' => '20%'))
         ));

    // Table contents.
    $counter = 1;
    $rows=array();
    echo $this->Form->create(null,array('action' => 'sell_cattle'));
    foreach ($animals as $animal) {
        $row=array();
        $row[] = $counter;
        $row[] = $animal['eartag'];
        $row[] = $animal['name'];
        $actions = array();
        'action' => 'edit', $animal['id']));
        $actions[] = $this->Form->checkbox('sell', array(
            'type' => 'checkbox', 
            'value' => $animal['sell'],
            'label' => 'Sell',
            'hiddenField' => false
        ));
        $row[] = array(
            implode(' ', $actions),
            array('class' => 'actions'),
        );
        $rows[]=$row;
        $counter = $counter + 1;
    }
    if (!empty($rows)) {
        echo $this->Html->tableCells($rows);
    }
?>  
</table>
</div>
<div>;
<?php

    echo $this->Form->button(__('Sell Selected Animals'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>

</div>
```

I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple or perhaps I'm approaching the problem the wrong way and there is a simpler, 'automagic' way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Let me know if I've not provided enough information and thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: While you explain what is your global objective, you do not explain what you expect for this particular code and what you get (and what is the difference between both) so it is very difficult for us to point you in any direction.

Comment: Thanks Holt.  What I was expecting was the checkbox variable to be populated with '1' for those checked, which woulod allow me to identify which animals were chosen for sale.  Once I had that, processing the records should be simple.
What I am getting is the following (using debug on $this->request):
object(CakeRequest) {
 params => array(
  'plugin' => null,
  'controller' => 'animals',
  'action' => 'sell_cattle',
  'named' => array(),
  'pass' => array()
 )
 data => array(
  'Animal' => array(
   'sell' => '0'
  )
 )
 query => array()
 url => 'animals/sell_cattle'

(etc...too long)